# Populating a cell based on two values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 cells, N3, Q3 and R3.
If N3 has a date in and Q3 is empty I want to report NO in cell R3.
If N3 has no date but Q3 has a date I want to report YES in cell R3.
IF Both N3 and Q3 are blank then R3 needs to be blank also.

How do I do this please?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If both N3 and Q3 have dates, what is the result of R3?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, it isn't clean or neat, but it also accounts for both cells having information.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(Q3),NOT(ISBLANK(N3))),"NO",IF(AND(ISBLANK(N3),NOT(ISBLANK(Q3))),"YES",IF(AND(ISBLANK(N3),ISBLANK(Q3)),"","?")))
```

[image]

Please note, this will not work correctly if you use the cells for something other than dates as well as it is only checking for blank values or not.